# Is there is any difference between the way we call the view in the web.php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

i just watch the way of calling the created view in web.php file

```
route::get('customer', function(){
    return view('customer');
})

route::view('/',customer);`
```

both the method do the same work, is there is any difference between them in security ,are in some other way

Comment: If you need to do stuff in your controller (like getting some data from a service or something), then you should go with the first option. If you just need to show a view without doing stuff before it's presented, you can go with the second. Regarding security, I don't see any reason for one to be safer than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you working with Laravel then you want to do stuff for your controller (like getting a service data), should go with the option first. If you have to show a scene without doing stuff before being presented, you can go with another.